# Buffers vs tabs vs arglist vs windows

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, tabbed-user-interface

So many choices!  So confusing!

1. When should one be used in preference to another?
2. How do these relate to each other?
3. What are the differences between them, anyway?
4. How do they affect commands you type in?
5. How do they relate to registers, macros, marks, options, and command history?
6. Which nest inside which others, for example is a tab a subdivision of a window like in typical GUI programs, or is a window a subdivision of a tab?
7. How does this relate to multiple command line arguments (the arglist) accessible through `:next` and `:prev`?
8. And lastly, which of these (if any) are `vi` compatible?

Comment: I was going to "post Q&A style" and make it a community wiki, but I realized when I expanded my question list a bit that I actually don't understand these nearly well enough to begin the wiki.  Maybe to clean up the wording a little once it's made.

Comment: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708822/why-do-vim-experts-prefer-buffers-over-tabs/26710166#26710166)?

Comment: That's exactly the explanation I was hoping for...although I was hoping to get it written *here*.  (We want to get the site past beta!)  :)  Didn't realize it already existed.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: And didn't realize at first that you wrote it.  :)  I have some little follow up points I want to get clarified; I'll post them in the comments over there if I don't find the answers by reading through.

Comment: Looks like buffers and arglist are the exact same thing.  That part was confusing me.  So you can't add a new buffer without adding to the arglist, and vice versa.  Correct?

Comment: No, the argument list is a subset of the buffer list.

Comment: Initially each argument creates a buffer, but then buffers and arguments start having their own independent lives.  You can change the list of arguments with `:args` (which doesn't change buffers), and you can delete buffers, including the ones corresponding to arguments, with `:bdelete` (which doesn't affect the list of arguments).  Editing new files with `:e` creates new buffers, and so does, say, opening help, but neither changes the list of arguments.  And so on, and so forth; you can't rely on any relation between the two beyond startup.

Comment: I've just asked a [similar question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11928/what-are-viewport-layout-and-workspace-in-relation-to-tabs). It's disappointing that you haven't had an answer to this yet. However, reading your question it's hard to get at exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @icc97, see the link in romainl's first comment above.  That answered this question fully.  Just happens to be on SO instead of here.

Comment: I actually found that answer very unhelpful, everything was layered in Vim terms whilst insulting other text editors. It's great if you already know what tab pages are, but not helpful if you're trying to learn. For that question I found [Jonathan Brink's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26745051/327074) easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly new here, so not allowed to comment and have to post this as an answer.
I guess romainl's answer is pretty definitive and there's this post that makes for a good 'beginner-friendly' version of it:
https://dockyard.com/blog/2013/10/22/vim-buffers

And then there's this post, maybe a little biased, but lays out the argument pretty well:
https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/

Comment: You can easily convert your post to a full-scaled answer by copying the most essential parts of the links here. Btw, also link-only answers are forbidden, because nobody wants a site full with answers full with rotten links. But the workaround is very easy (copy-paste the essential part) and quite attractive for the voters/reviewers.

Comment: The second link not mentioned arglist at all